# How can I send the Jenkins environmental variables as a response back to REST API?

Tags: jenkins

Generally, we can send the variables dynamically through the parameterized project in Jenkins using the REST API. Now, in the same way, I want to send Jenkins current build number as a response to REST API. Is it possible? or Any alternative way means any plugins could help to achieve this?

Could anybody suggest me on this?

Comment: Could you please clarify the use case? Like what would you like to do and what would be the expected result?

Comment: Hello @raspy. Thank for your response. My use case is, to send the current build number as a variable via Jenkins REST API. One more question I have is, let us assume we have 5 build number. One is in-progress and remaining are in Queue. Now which build number is my latest build number? running one or latest number in Queue?